# How can I change a fortigate hostname through fortimanager API

Tags: python, fortigate

I'm working on a script that changes the hostname of a fortigate through fortimanager API.

I have found a field called hostname in the FMG gui, but whenever I change this field the change is not reflected on the device itself.

The device i'm looking at is a FG-100E to be specific.

These are the calls I've used to change the hostname under cli config->system->global ->hostname in the fmg gui, and the device name on the device manager dashboard.

The api calls work to change the device name and the hostname under the cli config, however the hostname change is not reflected on the dashboard or the device.

Thanks in advance if anyone knows how to get these changes reflected.

`

```
    # API call to change fmg hostname in gui at cli config level.
        fmg.fmgInstance.update(

            f"pm/config/device/{hostname}/global/system/global",
            hostname=new_hostname.upper()

        )
     # API call to change fmg device name
        fmg.fmgInstance.execute(

            "dvm/cmd/update/device", adom="root", 
            device=new_hostname.upper()

        )
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply 2 strategies:

1. Modify the hostname through a proxy call to your FMG:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "exec",
  "params": [
    {
      "data": {
        "action": "put",
        "resource": "/api/v2/cmdb/system/global",
        "payload": {
            "hostname": "<new_hostname>"
        },
        "target": [
          "adom/{{adom}}/device/{{device1}}"
        ]
      },
      "url": "/sys/proxy/json"
    }
  ],
  "session": "{{session}}"
}
```

The modification will occurred only on FortiGate and the auto-retrieved feature will sync the configuration after a delay.

> Note: Fortimanager must be set to [auto-retrieved](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortimanager/7.4.2/administration-guide/229356/auto-update-and-auto-retrieve) enable (which is the default setting)

2. Change the FMG DVMDB and install the modification on the device.

Change config in Device DB:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "set",
  "params": [
    {
      "data": {
        "hostname": "<new_hostname>"
      },
      "url": "/pm/config/device/{{device}}/global/system/global"
    }
  ],
  "session": "{{session}}"
}
```

Install device:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "exec",
    "params": [
        {
            "url": "/securityconsole/install/device",
            "data": {
                "adom": "{{adom}}",
                "scope": [
                    {
                        "name": "{{device}}",
                        "vdom": "root"
                    }
                ],
                "flags": [
                    "none"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "session": "{{session}}",
    "verbose": 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try this first thing in the morning. Do you know if anything in my question would be considered sensitive information that I should omit?

Comment: I guess if you are not planning a firmware upgrade anytime soon, you should remove FMG version. But post modifications are stored on the stackoverflow anyway

Comment: I had a talk with fmg engineers today about this issue today so for now the matter is on hold. Thank you for keeping an eye on this. I 'll update you asap

Comment: The first method seemed to work! I'm using a postman collection and have noticed that most examples omit "id", and "jsonrpc." What is the reason for including those? p.s. the second option is what I had tried but failed.

Comment: `id` is use to identify a response from FortiManager.  `id` in a JSON request is always same as the `id` in the response. It can be useful with asynchronous programs.
`jsonrpc` on the other hand... In old FMG versions, I found different responses with and without. With current version, it's probably useless.